# Unregister(this) unregisters this instance from everything?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using the [mvvm light toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) for a project and I used to explicitly unregister to all the types of messages each instance was registered to, like this:

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister<MessageType1>(this);
Messenger.Default.Unregister<MessageType2>(this);
...
```

But is this

```
Messenger.Default.Unregister(this);
```

giving me the same result if I want to unregister to everything ? (for example in the Cleanup method of a ViewModel) I would assume so, but I did not find any hard evidence that my assumption was right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I browsed the source code for a moment, and it does appear that `Messenger.Default.Unregister(this)` will unregister the target object from any actions it registered previously.